# MaxLength DataAnnontation not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, data-annotations

I am trying to create a new Orchard CMS Module to mimic another MVC  project I built. I am using VS 2013 Express for both with the most recent Orchard v1.72.  I have a class that includes the using statement

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

I have the following properties

```
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public virtual string Symbol { get; set; }

    [StringLength(16)]
    public virtual string SymbolSequence { get; set; }

    [StringLength(512)]
    public virtual string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual double Begin { get; set; }

    public virtual double End { get; set; }

    [Range(0.01, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value 0.01 or larger.")]
    public virtual double Increment { get; set; }
```

Is there any reason that the MaxLength annotation cannot be found while the StringLength and Range annotations are?

They all reside in the same System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace and there is no problem in the other project.

How can I fix it?

Edit  Retargeting for .NET 4.5 seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

The `MaxLength` `DataAnnotation` was introduced in .NET Framework 4.5.

`StringLength` and `Range` were introduced in 3.5 SP1.